# How to set R Version in .Rproj file?

Tags: r, rstudio

I can set the R version in RStudio globally but do not know how to set it for a specific project such that a specific version of R is opened when opening a project. How do you guys do that?

Comment: You can follow these steps: File -> New Project -> New Directory -> New Project -> (Create your own one)

Comment: thx! I changed the first line from `Version: 1` to `Version 3.6.3` and now RStudio crashes stating: `Project ... could not be opened: Version not correctly specified in project config file`. I thought that the version field is for the Proj. file version?

Comment: RProj doesn't manage R version. This [link](https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/254) might help.

Comment: thx! That's great!